# c# Query collect values from all children

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

[image]

In the picture above, how to deal with parents with children and raise children by level?

I want a total query of the total father of all his sons as in the picture attached.

Comment: What is the rule that decides which rows in Table2 are connected to which rows in Table1?  The ones you selected in the picture above do not have the same id or name, so what decides?

Comment: treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
         
           
            treeView1.Nodes.Add("0", "Accounting Guide");
            foreach (var item in listAcc() )
            {
                TreeNode[] node = treeView1.Nodes.Find (item.MainAcc.ToString (),true);
                if (node !=null )
                {
                    node[0].Nodes.Add(item.IDAcc.ToString(), "(" + item.IDAcc.ToString() + ")" + item.NameAcc.ToString());
               }
            }
            }catch
            {
                return;
            }

          
        }

Comment: I'm not English. I can not express my feelings and thank you for your answer

Comment: p1 , p2  its parents     (p11,p12,p111) childern are p1  ,    (p21,p22,p211) childern are p2  thanks DancingFooll